# "invokeLater (Runnable obj)" - duda

Tags: java, java-swing

aunque ya he diseñado algunas aplicaciones en Java estoy siguiendo un manual del lenguaje para asentar la base de dicho lenguaje. He llegado a la parte de SWING.

En el manual crean una clase de ejemplo en la que se crea un objeto de tipo JFrame, le añaden un JLabel, lo hacen visible, etc, etc (el típico ejemplo).

Lo que me ha llamado la atención es que, en el método main de la clase que usan para visualizar el ejemplo usan el siguiente código:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      new SwingDemo(); //Donde SwinDemo es la clase con JFrame
   }
});
```

Además, dicen: "..., no puede crear directamente una instancia de un objeto SwingDemo. En su lugar debe crear un objeto Runnable que se ejecute..."

Me llama la atención porque, en los ejemplos que yo he seguido y modificado, para diseñar mis GUI de SWING lo que hacía era crear la clase SwingDemo como una clase que hereda directamente de JFrame y en el main de mis programas crear una instancia de dicha clase, por ejemplo:

```
SwingDemo guiEjemplo = new SwinDemo();
```

¿Alguien podría explicarme por qué se debe usar una forma u otra?, ¿Alguna de las dos es incorrecta?, ¿Poco eficiente?.

Gracias

Comment: Buenas!. En el manual que sigo yo, literalmente dice esto:
El método main crea un objeto de la clase 'SwingDemo' en tu caso, usando el método invokeLater, que es el encargado de que la tarea de crear la ventana se ejecute en un hijo de ejecución específico para la interfaz gráfica. Este hilo se denomina EDT (Event Dispatching Thread), es decir, el hilo de gestión de eventos.
Esta es la fórmula recomendada en lanzamiento de una aplicación con interfaz gráfica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Swing's Threading Policy:

En general, Swing no es seguro para subprocesos. Se debe acceder a todos los componentes de Swing y las clases relacionadas, a menos que se documente lo contrario, en el hilo de envío del evento.
Las aplicaciones típicas de Swing procesan en respuesta a un evento generado a partir de un gesto de usuario. Por ejemplo, al hacer clic en un JButton se notifican todos los ActionListeners agregados al JButton. Como todos los eventos generados a partir de un gesto de usuario se envían en la secuencia de envío del evento, la restricción no afecta a la mayoría de los desarrolladores.

Sin embargo, donde está el impacto radica en construir y mostrar una aplicación Swing. Las llamadas al método principal de una aplicación, o métodos en Applet, no se invocan en el hilo de envío del evento. Como tal, se debe tener cuidado de transferir el control al hilo de envío del evento al construir y mostrar una aplicación o applet. La forma preferida de transferir el control y comenzar a trabajar con Swing es usar invokeLater. El método invokeLater programa un Runnable para ser procesado en el hilo de envío del evento. Los dos ejemplos siguientes funcionan igual de bien para transferir el control y poner en marcha una aplicación Swing:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyApp implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // Invoked on the event dispatching thread.
        // Construct and show GUI.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MyApp());
    }
}
```

Or:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyApp {
    MyApp(String[] args) {
        // Invoked on the event dispatching thread.
        // Do any initialization here.
    }

    public void show() {
        // Show the UI.
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyApp(args).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Esta restricción también se aplica a los modelos adjuntos a los componentes Swing. Por ejemplo, si un modelo de tabla está conectado a una tabla JTable, el modelo de tabla solo debe modificarse en la cadena de distribución de eventos. Si modifica el modelo en un hilo separado, corre el riesgo de excepciones y posibles daños en la visualización.
Como todos los eventos se entregan en el hilo de envío del evento, se debe tener cuidado en el procesamiento de eventos. En particular, una tarea de larga ejecución, como la red io o el procesamiento computacional intensivo, ejecutada en el hilo de envío de eventos bloquea el envío de la cadena de envío de eventos para que no envíe otros eventos. Mientras que el hilo de envío del evento está bloqueado, la aplicación no responde por completo a la entrada del usuario. Consulte a SwingWorker para conocer la forma preferida de realizar dicho procesamiento cuando trabaje con Swing.

Informacion extraida de la api de java y literalmente traducido al español, para ver el original: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/